# How to calculate PMI when P(x,y) = 0?

Tags: probability, estimation, mutual-information

I'm trying to calculate PMI using probabilities estimated using binary occurrence counts from a set of documents. In short:

$P(x)$ = *# documents x appears in / # documents*
$P(y)$ = *# documents y appears in / # documents*
$P(x,y)$ = *# documents x and y appear in / # documents*

$PMI(x,y) = log\left(\frac{P(x, y)}{P(x)P(y)}\right)$

My question is: how do I handle the case where $P(x,y)=0$ , where $x$ and $y$ appear in no documents together?

Comment: What is PMI?  I found many acronyms online.

Comment: What will you be using these results for?  That will help determine what to do when $P(x,y)=0.$

Comment: I'm using it to calculate Semantic Orientation, for the purpose of Sentiment Analysis.